# What is the best way to put this expression inside this set of quotes?

Tags: php, quotes, ternary-operator

What is the best way to put this expression:

```
echo isset($GLOBALS['_url']) ? htmlspecialchars($GLOBALS['_url']) : ''
```

inside this parameter:

```
<?php
    echo "
    <input type='text' value=' *INSERT EXPRESSION* ' />
    ";
?>
```

I'm not sure what the best way to deal with the quotes inside of quotes, so any help is appreciated. I'm aware that this can be avoided by changing the overall syntax, but nevertheless, given these restrictions, how can I best do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you’re using single quoted attribute values, you need to set the `ENT_QUOTES` flag to get `'` also encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to do this...

```
<?php
    $exp = isset($GLOBALS['_url']) ? htmlspecialchars($GLOBALS['_url']) : '';

    echo "<input type='text' value=' $exp ' />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines maybe?

```
<?php
    echo "
    <input type='text' value='" . 
        (isset($GLOBALS['_url']) ? htmlspecialchars($GLOBALS['_url']) : '') . 
    "' />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways:

Method 1:

```
<?php
    $expression = isset($GLOBALS['_url']) ? htmlspecialchars($GLOBALS['_url']) : '';

    echo "
    <input type='text' value='$expression' />
    ";
?>
```

Method 2:

```
<?php
    $expression = isset($GLOBALS['_url']) ? htmlspecialchars($GLOBALS['_url']) : '';

    echo "
    <input type='text' value='" . $expression . "' />
    ";
?>
```

Method 3:

```
<?php
    echo "
    <input type='text' value='" . isset($GLOBALS['_url']) ? htmlspecialchars($GLOBALS['_url']) : '' . "' />
    ";
?>
```

**Update:**
Method 4: I would use either method 4 or 5, because that is faster to process by PHP. The change here is I am using single quotes instead of double.

```
<?php
    echo '
    <input type="text" value="' . isset($GLOBALS['_url']) ? htmlspecialchars($GLOBALS['_url']) : '' . '" />
    ';
?>
```

Method 5:

```
<?php
    $expression = isset($GLOBALS['_url']) ? htmlspecialchars($GLOBALS['_url']) : '';

    echo '
    <input type="text" value="' . $expression . '" />
    ';
?>
```

Comment: You just copied the two answers and pasted as a new answer.. :) Good job.. :)

Comment: you guys beat me in my answer :(

Answer (score 0):

I always use [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf).

```
<?php

    printf("\n<input type='text' value='%s' />\n", isset($GLOBALS['_url']) ? htmlspecialchars($GLOBALS['_url']) : '');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
    define('URL',isset($GLOBALS['_url']) ? htmlspecialchars($GLOBALS['_url']) : '');
    echo "<input type='text' value=' ".URL." ' />";
?>
```